# If statement check

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an if statement that loops through csv data.  There are 51 rows that I have parsed in by new lines and by commas to give me individual arrays for each row.  My issue is my if statement doesn't seem to be working and honestly I just don't see why. Raw is the csv file.

Updated heres how i split the csv file

```
        console.log("Loaded: " + data.length);
        console.log("feature layer graphics: " + fl.graphics.length);
        console.log(data);

        var raw = data.split("\n");                                                       
        var valMin = Infinity;
        var valMax = -Infinity;
        var arrayForBreaks = [];
```

console logs returns 51 false
then there is one console log of true

```
for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
    var row = raw[i].split(",");
    var name = " ";
    var amount = " ";

    if (row.length >= 6) {
        name = row[0];
        amount = row[1];
    }

    console.log(isNaN(row[1]));

    stateData[name] = row;
    valMin = Math.min(valMin, row[1]);
    valMax = Math.max(valMax, row[1]);
    arrayForBreaks.push(parseFloat(amount));

}; //end for loop
```

So my question is in the if statement I'm checking to see if the length of the first element in the array is greater that 6 if it is dump that name and amount in those variables.  I also had a else statement to fill in the last array.  But it seems to keep adding one empty line to the end of the data.

Comment: Think about this (valid!) csv line: `"ABC,XYZ",1,,"25,50"` - how many fields are in this string?  According to your code, 5 - but actually there are only 3.

Comment: Are you sure after the split operation, the length the **row** variable is more than 6 ? i guess you should even post the value of **Row** in your question ,for better understaning

Comment: Also, you may want to check if a line is empty and skip it - it's quite likely that there's `\n` at the end of the original input file.

Comment: As @AleksG said, I would check for empty lines. I bet you have an empty line at the end of your file.

Comment: What you expect it to log on the console? If `row[1]` can be converted to a number, `isNaN()` returns `false` as expected. The last `true` is probably coming from an empty last line in the CSV file, since `isNaN('')` returns `true`. Also that last line actually also contains an `EOF` mark, though it should not be read to the `raw` at the first place.

Comment: yea there is an empty line at the end of the data and thats what i'm trying to get rid of because once it his that line and errors out every thing esle then afterwards errors out also

Comment: @TroyBryant I've to make a rollback to my comment above, `isNaN('')` returns `false` as well, maybe `raw` is containing the `EOF`? Just remove the last line from the `raw` with `raw.pop()` before iterating it through.

Comment: Thanks now that work...raw.pop() it was just one extra line before entering the for loop that was crashing it before it started.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is in the if statement I'm checking to see if the length of the first element in the array is greater that

Negative.

You are checking to see if there are more than 6 elements in the array, or 6 comma delimited items.

To check the length of the first element you would need to:

```
 if (row[0].length >= 6) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

> […] in the if statment I'm checking to see if the lengh of the first element in the array is greater tha[n] 6

No, that’s not what you are doing. `row.length` will return the number of elements of `row` – and `row` is an array you got from splitting the raw string by commas. If you want to check the length of the first element, you should check `row[0].length` instead.

Comment: I just put that in there and see what you were saying but it still has 52 rows and the last row being blank

Comment: Then you should probably check for empty lines first and skip those?